# Remove Items from Array - Angular 4

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I'm working on a simple todo app in Angular4. I have the app setup in the following way:

Form Component: This is the form to add items to the to-do list
Item Component: This is the individual component.
App Component: I have a *ngFor look here going to list all of the todo items.

I've added a new button on the item component that is supposed to delete the item, however I can't figure out how to "find" or "locate" the correct index number for the item to splice or filter it out.
I've included a link to the [github repository here](https://github.com/gurgeng/ToDo)

app.component.html:

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div class="container">
  <app-form (itemAdded)="onItemAdded($event)"></app-form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3"
    *ngFor="let item of toDoList; let i=index">
      <app-item
      [listItem]="item"
      (itemDeleted)="onItemDeleted($event)"></app-item>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  toDoList = [
    {
      name: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'
    }
  ];

  onItemAdded(itemData: {itemName: string}){
    this.toDoList.push({
      name: itemData.itemName
    });
  }
  onItemDeleted(index: number){
    this.toDoList.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

form.component.html:

```
<div class="title">
  <h1 class="display-4">{{ title }}</h1>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="newItem">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" (click)="onAddItem()">
      <fa name="plus"></fa>
    </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

form.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() itemAdded = new EventEmitter<{itemName: string}>();
  title = 'To-Do List';
  newItem = '';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onAddItem(){
    this.itemAdded.emit({itemName: this.newItem});
  }

}
```

item.component.html:

```
<div class="task">
  <div class="mb-5 d-flex justify-content-between">
    <fa name="circle-o" size="3x"></fa>
    <button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger align-self-end" (click)="onDeleteItem()"><fa name="trash"></fa></button>
  </div>
  {{item.name}}
</div>
```

item.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item',
  templateUrl: './item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item.component.css']
})
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('listItem') item: {name: string};
  @Output() itemDeleted = new EventEmitter<{index: number}>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onDeleteItem() {
    this.itemDeleted.emit() //need help with this
  }
}
```

Comment: I get that you can splice or filter it out the top answer starts off by saying:
"First, find the index of the element you want to remove"

This is what I'm trying to find out how to do. I want to find out what the index is based on the item they are trying to delete

Comment: Do not link to external resources without adding a digest of that resource here on Stack Overflow.  Bring relevant code here.  We should not need to visit your GitHub to help you.

Comment: If you need our help, can you at least show us your code instead of pointing us to somewhere else where we still need to search for your code ourselves?

Comment: you don't have any Output in your item Component that is called `itemDeleted` to write this `<app-item (itemDeleted)="onItemDeleted($event)"></app-item>`

Comment: @Med_Ali_Rachid I just added the following to my item.component.ts file:
`@Output() itemDeleted = new EventEmitter<{index: number}>();`

Comment: what r u doing in your code is not logic , why u have the `onDeleteItem()` in item.component.ts , and your todo list isn't in the same component ?

Comment: you are inputting item to app-item which is name of the item, what you can do it to emit this name and in the onItemDeleted(name: string) in your app.component you will get the name and find out index from the array from the name and splice the array, to make it easier you can also input the whole item to app-item which will have the item index as well,then you can emit item index directly!

Comment: Because that is a single to do item. I use my app component and event emitters to listen to button click actions, and pass data from child to parent, the parent to child.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try like this :

```
<app-item [listItem]="item" (itemDeleted)="onItemDeleted(i)"></app-item>

onItemDeleted(index){ 
    this.toDoList.splice(index, 1); 
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i started of trying to do, but it is saying cannot find name index

Comment: you might be getting that error because you are not passing "i" in the method **onItemDeleted(i)** which in the above stated answer he is, try that!

Comment: @JayDeeEss So I created the following output: `@Output() itemDeleted = new EventEmitter<{index: number}>();`

and I'm beginning to write the code for onDeleteItem, but not exactly sure what I should include in it... what I have so far:
`onDeleteItem() {
    this.itemDeleted.emit()
  }`

I just updated all of the code to include what I have done so far

Comment: Nevermind, adding what I added, did the trick, Should I specify what is being emitted? when using: `this.itemDeleted.emit()`

Answer (score 4):

You can use .filter():

```
onDeleteItem(id: number) {
    this.list = this.list.filter(item => item.id !== id);
}
```

or you can user [.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), but to use it you will need to get the index of the item in the array:

```
const index: number = functionToGetTheIndex();
this.list.splice(index, 1);
```

To get the index you can do something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
   if(this.list[i].id === id) {
     return i;
   }
}
```

*Edit: int should be number

Comment: I know I can use both of those methods, what I need to figure out is how to find the index of the current item in the array

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the other two answers while I was posting.

Comment: there is no `int` type in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your code, a simple way to delete items from your array.

```
myArray = myArray.filter(x => x.ITEM !== ITEM);
```

*Edit: spelling

Answer (score 0):

You can use the folowing code :

at the start we announce rowItems :

```
rowItems: RowItems= new RowItems(0, "", "", new Array<Something>());
```

....
method in code

```
deleteRowOfSomething(rowIndex: number) {
        console.log("removing row index: " + rowIndex);
        this.rowItems.splice(rowIndex, 1);
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    }
```

don`t forget to import libraries for changeDetectorRef.